# manage cookies within webrequest

Tags: c#, cookies, webrequest

i want to make a web request while rearrange cookies in c#.

I'm handling cookies with

```
public CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();
```

when i look at the _cookies element i see that non-public members -> domain=.local

I want to change .local variable.

becuase i think website gets authenticated with this value.

i tried to add this cookie but website gives me 401 error

```
request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("Domain", "bb.local"));
```

how can i manage cookies

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".